# Duda simple lista de listas en Python

Tags: python

Estoy empezando con *Python*, trataba de editar una lista, pero descubrí que no podía hacerlo, dado que los ***strings son inmutables***. Encontré ésta solución:

```
lista = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

lista_temp = []
a=3
b="c"

for i in range(0,len(lista)):
    if i==a:
        lista_temp.append(b)

    else:
        lista_temp.append(lista[i])

print(lista_temp)
```

Resultado de la impresión:

> [0,0,0,"c",0]

Quisiera poder hacer lo mismo con una lista de listas, es decir,
que esto:

```
lista=[[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]]
```

... pase a ser esto:

```
lista_temp=[[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[["c",0,0],[0,0,0]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer eso no es necesario complicarte la vida con tres `for` anidados (si no hay una causa que te fuerce a ello), usa [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) de la biblioteca estándar que hace una copia 'muerta' del objeto que quieras, posteriormente usas los índices para cambiar los valores en la copia:

```
from copy import deepcopy

lista=[[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]]

x = 1
y = 0
z = 0
c = 'c'

lista_temp = deepcopy(lista)
lista_temp[x][y][z] = c
```

Ten en cuenta que tienes una matriz tridimencional, necesitas especificar las coordenadas en tres ejes (`x`, `y`, `z`) para asignar el valor.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias :)

Comment: existe alguna manera en que pueda hacerte una pregunta por interno?

Comment: @DonFelipe si te refieres a contactar por privado en [es.so] no hay forma de hacerlo y tampoco se promueve, entre otras cosas porque la idea del sitio es que las preguntas/respuestas sean de utilidad a todos los usuarios y no solo al que pregunta. Si no fuera algo que mereciera o no quisieras hacer una pregunta se podria hablar por el [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com). Eso si, tampoco son privadas las comversaciones. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, primero lo primero: 
las "listas" van entre `[]` y las tuplas van entre `()` ...  una tupla es inmutable, una lista en cambio se puede modificar.

por ende los siguiente NO es inmutable (se puede modificar):

```
lista = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Para que sea inmutable debería ser reemplazado (por ejemplo):

```
secuencia = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

En este contexto, si tiene sentido hablar de construir `lista_temp`. de la otra forma simplemente modificaríamos `lista`. Al margen de esta aclaración el procedimiento siguiente es análogo

Python y muchos lenguajes (que incorporan ciertas caracteristicas del paradigma funcional) incorporan "slicing" es decir puedes cortar  cadenas con indicar los indices, a su vez copiar su contenido en otros elementos referenciandolos correctamente:

```
>>>lista = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>>lista_temp = lista[:3] + list("c") + lista[4:]
>>> lista_temp
[0, 0, 0, 'c', 0]
```

No es necesario realizar ningun bucle `for`, esto sería con respecto al primer caso. 
Por otro lado en el ejemplo que se muestra despues hay un problema en cuanto a la dimensionalidad (o anidamiento) de las listas:

```
lista=[[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]]
```

tiene dos elementos (esto se vería si se ejecuta `len(lista)`). por ende en `lista_temp=[[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[["c",0,0],[0,0,0]]]` se modifico el segundo elemento de la lista (mejor dicho el primer elemento del segundo elemento de la lista principal), que NO es lo mismo que se muestra en el primer ejemplo donde el cuarto elemento es modificado. (Hay que tener en cuenta que los indices comienzan a partir de cero por ende cuando el condicional comprueba que `a=3`, esta comprobando que está en el cuarto elemento)

De todas maneras aquí pongo como se haría usando slicing (para que quede como en el segundo ejemplo):

```
>>> lista=[[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]]
>>> lista_temp = lista[:1] + [ ["c",0,0] + lista[1][1:]]
>>> lista_temp
[[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], ['c', 0, 0, [0, 0, 0]]]
```

Comment: Si se quiere mantener el mismo anidamiento también resulta:                `>>> lista_temp[1][0][0] = "c"`
Pero solo es útil para este caso en particular.