# Python - evitar cambio de valor en una variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

Buenas tardes

El problema es que la primer funcion cambia el valor de mi lista, y la segunda funcion toma la lista modificada como parametro, y quiero que la segunda funcion tambien tome la lista original como parametro.

```
import math
import Queue


Uinicial = raw_input("Ingrese numeros aleatoriamente del 0-8: ")
Einicial = map(int, str(Uinicial))
Efinal = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0]
posicion_de_cero = Einicial.index(0)
cola = Queue.Queue()


def movimiento_izquierda(posicion_de_cero,Einicial):
    #Movimiento hacia a la Izquierda
    Einicial
    izq_inicial = Einicial
    print izq_inicial
    new_posicion_izquierda = posicion_de_cero - 1
    izq_inicial[posicion_de_cero], izq_inicial[new_posicion_izquierda] = izq_inicial[new_posicion_izquierda], izq_inicial[posicion_de_cero]
    print izq_inicial

def movimiento_derecha(posicion_de_cero,Einicial):
    #Movimiento hacia a la derecha
    der_inicial = Einicial
    print der_inicial
    new_posicion_derecha = posicion_de_cero + 1
    der_inicial[posicion_de_cero], der_inicial[new_posicion_derecha] = der_inicial[new_posicion_derecha], der_inicial[posicion_de_cero]
    print der_inicial

movimiento_izquierda(posicion_de_cero,Einicial)
movimiento_derecha(posicion_de_cero,Einicial)
```

Answer (score 2):

Si no quieres que se modifique tu lista `Einicial` debes hacer una copia en profundida de ella y no:

```
izq_inicial = Einicial
```

Con esto solo haces que ambas variables referencien al mismo objeto en memoria, por lo tanto modificar una implica modificar la otra (son el mismo objeto `list`). Para crear una copia en profundidad (deep copy) usa [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html):

```
import copy
import math
import Queue


Uinicial = raw_input("Ingrese numeros aleatoriamente del 0-8: ")
Einicial = map(int, str(Uinicial))
Efinal = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0]
posicion_de_cero = Einicial.index(0)
cola = Queue.Queue()


def movimiento_izquierda(posicion_de_cero,Einicial):
    #Movimiento hacia a la Izquierda
    Einicial
    izq_inicial = copy.deepcopy(Einicial)
    print izq_inicial
    new_posicion_izquierda = posicion_de_cero - 1
    izq_inicial[posicion_de_cero], izq_inicial[new_posicion_izquierda] = izq_inicial[new_posicion_izquierda], izq_inicial[posicion_de_cero]
    print izq_inicial

def movimiento_derecha(posicion_de_cero,Einicial):
    #Movimiento hacia a la derecha
    der_inicial = copy.deepcopy(Einicial)
    print der_inicial
    new_posicion_derecha = posicion_de_cero + 1
    der_inicial[posicion_de_cero], der_inicial[new_posicion_derecha] = der_inicial[new_posicion_derecha], der_inicial[posicion_de_cero]
    print der_inicial

movimiento_izquierda(posicion_de_cero,Einicial)
movimiento_derecha(posicion_de_cero,Einicial)
```

Comment: que diferencia hay con `izq_inicial =Einicial[:]` o `izq_inicial =list(Einicial)` ?

Comment: Muchas gracias, por su respuesta.
De hecho ambas funcionaron

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que las listas se pasan por referencia de modo que básicamente tus funciones están operando sobre `EInicial`, lo puedes resolver fácilmente si en cada función realizas un `copy`a una nueva lista, por ejemplo: `nueva_lista = list(Einicial)`, tus dos funciones quedarían entonces:

```
def movimiento_izquierda(posicion_de_cero,Einicial):
    #Movimiento hacia a la IzquierdaEinicial
    nueva_lista = list(Einicial)
    izq_inicial = nueva_lista
    print izq_inicial
    new_posicion_izquierda = posicion_de_cero - 1
    izq_inicial[posicion_de_cero], izq_inicial[new_posicion_izquierda] = izq_inicial[new_posicion_izquierda], izq_inicial[posicion_de_cero]
    print izq_inicial

def movimiento_derecha(posicion_de_cero,Einicial):
    #Movimiento hacia a la derecha
    nueva_lista = list(Einicial)
    der_inicial = nueva_lista
    print der_inicial
    new_posicion_derecha = posicion_de_cero + 1
    der_inicial[posicion_de_cero], der_inicial[new_posicion_derecha] = der_inicial[new_posicion_derecha], der_inicial[posicion_de_cero]
    print der_inicial
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que esta forma de copiar no funcionaría como se espera si la lista tiene objetos, en dichos casos tenemos `copy.deepcopy()`. Te recomiendo la lectura de [este](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/71661/duda-simple-lista-de-listas-en-python/71663#71663) enlace.