# Evitar modificación de una lista python

Tags: python, lista

Tengo un problema en este código, estoy intentando resolver el 8puzzle, el problema se presenta a la hora de generar las posibles configuraciones de la configuración actual, cuando creo comienzo a crearlas a la función que me las crea le mando como argumento el estado actual y debe generarme una nueva para cada posible movimiento,
en la primera llamada lo hace bien, pero cuando la vuelvo a llamar el argumento que se supone es el estado actual tiene el valor del estado nuevo que se había creado 
y no entiendo por que pasa esto si alguien me pudiera ayudar a encontrar donde esta mi error se los agradecería mucho.

EDIT: Me di cuenta que el estado actual al mandarlo en la función para crear un nuevo estado se me modifica y toma el valor  del estado generado como evito esto.

Este es mi codigo.

```
init_ = [[1, 2, 3], [0, 5, 6], [4, 7, 8]]
ending_ = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 0]]

print('Estado inicial')
for k in init_:
    print(k)
notrepet = [] #nodos creados
_patch  = [] #camino
Cola_abiertos = [] #de donde sacaremso los nodos
#definiendo los movimientos
'''
arriba = 1
abajo = 0
izquierda = 2
derecha = 3
'''
lista_mov = [("arriba", 1), ("abajo", 0), ("izquierda", 2), ("derecha", 3)]

'''
FUNCION COMPLEMETO A LA FUNCION VALIDAR_MOV 
'''

def Validar_pos(pos, xy):
    if xy == 0: #verifacamos pos en x
        if pos[0] >= 0 and pos[0] < 3:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    elif xy == 1: #verificamos posicion en y
        if pos[1] >= 0 and pos[1] < 3:
            return True
        else:
            return False

'''
FUNCION PARA VALIDAR UN MOVIMIENTO SI ESTA DENTRO DEL TABLERO, si es valida retornamos la nueva pos
'''
def validar_mov(mov, estado_actual):
    if mov == 1:#si nos movemos arriba
        new_pos = (estado_actual[0]-1, estado_actual[1])# creamos nueva posicion
        if Validar_pos(new_pos, 0):#si retorna True por que la pos es valida
            return new_pos
        else:
            return False
    elif mov == 0:#si nos movemos abajo
        new_pos = (estado_actual[0]+1, estado_actual[1])# creamos nueva posicion
        if Validar_pos(new_pos, 0):#si retorna True por que la pos es valida
            return new_pos
        else:
            return False
    elif mov == 2:#si nos movemos izquierda
        new_pos = (estado_actual[0], estado_actual[1]-1)# creamos nueva posicion
        if Validar_pos(new_pos, 1):#si retorna True por que la pos es valida
            return new_pos
        else:
            return False
    if mov == 3:#si nos movemos derecha
        new_pos = (estado_actual[0], estado_actual[1]+1)# creamos nueva posicion
        if Validar_pos(new_pos, 1):#si retorna True por que la pos es valida
            return new_pos
        else:
            return 

def crear_tab(estado_actual, new_pos, old_pos):
    new_estado = list(estado_actual)
    back_num = estado_actual[new_pos[0]][new_pos[1]] #guardamos el valor que habia en la pos donde moveremos el 0
    new_estado[new_pos[0]][new_pos[1]] = 0 #colocamos el 0 en la nuevo posicion
    new_estado[old_pos[0]][old_pos[1]] = back_num # y el valor que estaba en new_pos lo pasamos a old_pos
    return new_estado.copy()

def calcular_heuristica(estado):
    hueristica = 0
    for lis1, lis2 in zip(estado, ending_):
        for p1, p2 in zip(lis1, lis2):
            if p1 != 1:
                if p1 != p2:
                    hueristica+=1
    return hueristica

def Crear_sucesor(estado_actual, mov, pos_cero):
    sucesor =set()
    test_pos = validar_mov(mov, pos_cero[0]) #como se trata de una lista que contiene un solo elemento lo sacamos y lo mandamos en forma de conjunto
    if test_pos: #si no es false, se trata de una posicion dentro del tablero
        new_estado = crear_tab(estado_actual, test_pos, pos_cero[0]) #Creamo un nuevo tablero
        print("estado genereado")
        for l in new_estado:
            print(l)
        if new_estado not in notrepet: #verificamos si no esta repetida esa configuracion
            h = calcular_heuristica(new_estado)
            sucesor = (new_estado, h)#Creamos el conjunto
            return sucesor
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False

Cola_abiertos.append((init_, 3)) #guardamos el estado inicial del tablero y le pasamos su heuristica

def Generar_sucesores(estado):
    estado_actual = estado.copy()
    sucesores = []
    pos_cero = [(estado_actual.index(sub_l),sub_l.index(0)) for sub_l in estado_actual if 0 in sub_l] #obtenemos la coordenada donde se encuentra el cero
    for mov in lista_mov:#aplicaremos todos los movimientos y analisaremos cuales son validos
        estado_test = Crear_sucesor(estado_actual, mov[1], pos_cero)
        if estado_test: #si me retorna un estado lo guardamos en la lista a sucesores que vamos a crear
            estado_test = list(estado_test)
            sucesores.append(estado_test.copy())#Guardamos 
    if sucesores:#si la lista no esta vacia
        return sucesores
    else:#si no se creo sucesores
        return False


nodo = Cola_abiertos[0][0] 
s = Generar_sucesores(init_)

print("")
print(s)
for estado in s:
    print ("estado")
    for cel in estado[0]:
        print(cel)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bueno por fin encontré como solucionarlo.

Como mi estado es una lista de lista al hacer list(estado) conseguía una copia de la lista superficial por así decirlo, pero las sublista seguían teniendo la misma referencia y se modificaban de igual manera.

En el post de abajo comentaron que para evitar esto se hacia una lista muerta, donde no solo hacia una copia de la lista "superficial" si que lo hacia con cada elemento de esta

De esta forma lo solucione

```
import copy

estado_actual = copy.deepcopy(estado)
```

Aqui encontre la solucion

[Python - evitar cambio de valor en una variable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/80535/python-evitar-cambio-de-valor-en-una-variable)

Comment: solo poner enlaces se considera de baja calidad: añade lo relevante del link aqui dándole clic en editar y solo deja la referencia al sitio como reconocimiento al autor original

Comment: Gracias por la observación